# Basic HTTP question: two session variables with different expiry dates?

Tags: django, http, session, cookies

This is a really basic HTTP question, but I can't find the answer by Googling with this terminology (I guess I'm using the wrong terminology).

I want to set two session-wide variables.

The two session variables should expire at different times. One should expire after 30 seconds, one should expire when the user closes the browser.

Should I use session variables, or cookies?

In other words, does the expiry date attach to the session variable, or to the session itself? And can I do this better with cookies?

In case it matters: I'm working in Django.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let me quote from [Django documentation on sessions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry):

> **set_expiry(value)**
>
> ```
> Sets the expiration time for the session.
> ```

So, this probably answers your question. The "expiry date" is for a session, not session variables. A session stores session variables. Therefore, session variables should expire along with the session. In other words, session variables can't expire at different times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no master but I would use cookies since that is simple as pie to set the timer on and has several options for your "destroy when close"-part, even though sessions will work neatly for the last part as well.

Comment: Thanks. The real question is: can session variables have different expiry dates?